# How can I create a field using the id from the same row in ActiveRecord Ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord

-----UPDATE-----

Well, seems that the problem was in `last.id`. When database is created works OK, but when not fails. Now the question is different: How can I create a field using the id from the same row?

--------ORIGINAL------

I'm working with active record in pure ruby (without Rails), and I'm literally getting crazy with this.
This is my code

```
class Enviroment < ActiveRecord::Base
    #self.table_name = 'enviroments'
    self.connection.create_table(:enviroments, :force=>true) do |t|
        t.column :name, :string, :default=>'env-'+ (last.id-1).to_s
        t.column :ssh, :string, :default=>nil
    end
end
```

and here the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'enviroments'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:465:in `table_structure'
```

if I use`self.table_name = 'enviroments'` still not working. I've updated the gems and neither. 
I'm newbie with ruby and databases, but I can't understand this problem, I think this same code worked in the past :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this was my solution:

```
class Enviroment < ActiveRecord::Base
after_create :create_default

private
def create_default
    if name == nil
        s = 'env-' + self.id.to_s
        self.name = s
        self.save
    end
end

end

class CreateSchema < ActiveRecord::Migration
create_table(:enviroments, :force=>true) do |t|
    t.column :name, :string, :default=>nil
    t.column :ssh, :string, :default=>nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to create the table (very odd to have that in the model by the way) is calling `last.id`, and of course to call `last` the table must already exist.

Because you're passing `:force => true` to `create_table` you'll actually destroy the table if it already exists.

You could probably make your code work if you stashed the value of `last.id` in a local variable before the call to `create_table` but I don't understand why you are creating tables like this.

Comment: sorry, we wrote at the same time. There is a way to resolve this?
Why is odd? Maybe I should use Migration instead of Base? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: The odd thing is creating a model's table from inside the model itself - typically you wouldn't want to recreate the table everytime the nodel's code was loaded.

Comment: Well I think I should learn more about this. I think I've found a correct way based on this: [link](http://tardigra.de/mcblog/2008/03/standalone-activerecord-and-sq.html). I'm creating tables inside a Migration class and seems to work right with a relation